# Select an item by id in spinner with custom objects

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

I have a class

```
zones
int id
String name
```

then I create a array list of this class, and set this to a arrayadapter to finaly show(name field) it  in a spinner.

But how I select a zone programaticaly if I have the id

Answer (score 0):

**With the Adapter class**
You can use the `getItem(int position)` method to get the object in the position in the adapter.

**Outside the Adapter** class or if the Adapter position does not match your class id, then to use class variable id, you need to do this.

Create a class Zones

```
public class Zones{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Zones(int id, String name){
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
      return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Store the class objects in a List Object

```
List<Zones> zonesList = new ArrayList<Zones>();

zonesList.add(new Zones(1, "Finland"));
zonesList.add(new Zones(1, "Sweden"));
zonesList.add(new Zones(1, "Finland"));
zonesList.add(new Zones(1, "Finland"));
```

To get an object with a class id variable, loop through the List and check for the Zones object with id equal to the given id.

```
for(Zones mZones : zonesList){
  if(mZones.getId() == id){ 
     // get the object your are looking for.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create model **Zones**

```
class Zones{
private int id;
private String name;

public Zones(int id, String name){
this.id=id;
this.name=name;
}

public int getId(){
return id;
}

public String getName(){
return name;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
return id+" - "+name;
}
```

*Now to set adapter,*

```
List<Zones> zonesList=new ArrayList<>();
zonesList.add(new Zones(1,"Name1"));
zonesList.add(new Zones(2,"Name2"));
zonesList.add(new Zones(3,"Name3"));
```

*Initialize yourSpinner then,*

```
yourSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                zonesList
));
```

**To get the selected item,**

***For id:***

```
((Zones)yourSpinner.getSelectedItem)).getId();
```

***For name:***

```
((Zones)yourSpinner.getSelectedItem)).getName();
```

***Or Simply use,***

```
yourSpinner.getSelectedItem.toString();
```

Comment: Use `getItemAtPosition(index)` to get the specific item at desired position